# What happens to the skill's XP upon training?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm levelling up my skills via the (player.)"incPCS" console command (don't judge me) and noticed that the XP-progression-to-the-next-level of the skill seems to stay at the same ratio. So, it got me wondering, does training work the same way? Or is it only the console command that causes the skill to keep the same XP progression, despite levelling? E.g., if it took only one more successful pickpocket or one more hitting-a-damageable-thing-with-a-one-handed-weapon to level up those respective skills, would it still only take one more successful use to level it up after training the skill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percentage stays the same, the total number of uses needed *might* increase.

Supposing you gain 10 XP of skill A for a certain action and you were lacking 10 XP to level up, after training the amount you need could have increased to 11; this is an edge example, of course.

AFAIK the console command and the trainers follow the same logic

Comment: You tested? I ask because your last line puts doubt in me.

Comment: I tested the trainers, didn't test the console commands.